# mongorestore is very slow on AWS DocumentDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongorestore, aws-documentdb

There is any way to make this operation faster?

I'm trying to restore my DB to the AWS DocumentDB, and probably it will take some weeks to finish... my overall data is less than 400MB.

dump is Gzipped

Comment: How are you restoring it? Which size are you using?

Comment: @mokugo-devops sorry I didn't understand, which size are you talking about?

Comment: Document db instance size

Comment: @mokugo-devops `db.r5.large` and i'm restoring via this command: `mongorestore --uri="...." dump --gzip`

Comment: @mokugo-devops using mongorestore from my MacBook to the DocumentDB

Comment: Could you test from using an EC2 instance to run the command? It might be quicker if it does not need to keep traversing the internet

Comment: No problem, added this as an answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To resolve this it was suggested to run the command from an EC2 instance rather than a remote host.

This enabled a speedy import.

The likely reason is the number of network based operations across the internet rather than a local network resource which has shorter latency between each interaction.

Comment: You can speed up your mongodump by increasing the number of parallel connections using the --numParallelCollections option https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/backup_restore-dump_restore_import_export_data.html